# Laravel 4.1 check database table last edit

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.1 and how do I get the timestamp of the last time a given database table was edited (by edit I mean if any data was changed in the table) ?

Comment: you dont know how to get it from database or what? And by last table edit you mean using `ALTER TABLE` or insert/edit record?

Comment: I can query the table fine (`$queue = DB::table($queueDetails->table_name)->get();`), I would like to know when was the last time the table was edited, by edit I mean data changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you use MyISAM or MySQL >= 5.7.2:

```
SHOW TABLE status FROM database LIKE 'table';
```

You'll receive several columns in which you'll find 'Update_time'.

Comment: I'm currently using InnoDB

Comment: I'm afraid the 'Update_time' column will be 'null' then. 
Do you have updated_at columns on the individual rows? In that case you could query for the latest?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, very much appreciated :)

Comment: From mysql changelog: Beginning with MySQL 5.7.2, UPDATE_TIME displays a timestamp value
for the last UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE performed on InnoDB tables.
Previously, UPDATE_TIME displayed a NULL value for InnoDB tables. So the question is - what is your mysql version ;)

Comment: currently on Server version: 5.6.16 :(, I will look into updating it. thanks again :)